# MP4 player for Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

Does any one no of a good MP4 player for Raspbian that takes up small amount of storage

It would need to be GUI or terminal run

Answer (score 2):

There is a video player for rasbian and it has been built in rasbian, it's called omxplayer, you can open a terminal, and type `man omxplayer` for more usage.